# How to check if AnimatedContainer is completely animating?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, widget

Hy everybody,

I try now to get status from `Animatedcontainer` widget, to set the State after it is finishing, but I cann't find so much info's about this feature in google, only one, this widget has `onEnd` void function, but also , I haven't any idea how to use this in my code.

could you have, idea how can this be doing?

Comment: Hi! Did you find the way?

Comment: Hi! yes, Sunkuu7 answer was my solution and fixed my error https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753922/9874190

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
AnimatedContainer(onEnd: (){
      // do something or update state
      setState(() {
        _didFinishAnimating = true;
      });
    });
```